# UBUNTU on My Device

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Hope everything is well, actually im trying to install ubuntu on XOLO X900 smartphone.
it has Intel 1.6 dual core atom processor, 1Gb of RAM 16Gb storage , which meets the hardware requirement of ubuntu capability device and you also have mentioned (http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/operators-and-oems) in your forum.
so please guide me the steps to install ubuntu on this device thank you.

Awaiting for you positive reply

Thnk you.